# Casting an int to a char. Not storing the correct value

Tags: c++, casting, char, int

I'm trying to store a number as a character in a char vector named code

```
code->at(i) = static_cast<char>(distribution(generator));
```

However it is not storing the way I think it should

[image: Value stored]

for some shouldn't '\x4' be the ascii value for 4? if not how do I achieve that result?

Here's another vector who's values were entered correctly.
[image]

Comment: `'\x4'` is .. `4`. Pretty sure you're thinking of `'4'` == `'\x34'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert int to char c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114741/how-to-convert-int-to-char-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting without actually converting the int to a char. You need:

```
code->at(i) = distribution(generator) + '0';
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. Thought I had forgotten something

Comment: Alternatively, why not simply setup a `uniform_int_distribution<char>` to simply range on `'0'` through `'9'` in the first place. If the purpose of this is to generate digit-chars `'0'` through `'9'`.

Answer (score 3):

No. `\xN` does not give you the ASCII code for the character `N`.

`\xN` *is* the ASCII character<sup>†</sup> whose code is `N` (in he**x**adecimal form).

So, when you write `'\x4'`, you get the [unprintable] character with the ASCII code 4. Upon conversion to an integer, this value is still 4.

If you wanted the ASCII character that looks like `4`, you'd write `'\x34'` because 34 is `4`'s ASCII code. You could also get there using some magic, based on numbers in ASCII being contiguous and starting from `'0'`:

```
code->at(i) = '0' + distribution(generator);
```

<sup><sup>†</sup> Ish.</sup>